# Avisar quando o arquivo for alterado utilizando PHP ou JavaScript

Tags: php, javascript

Tenho um formulário que salva os dados em um arquivo `.txt`. Gostaria de saber se tem como criar um aviso para saber quando um novo conteúdo for registrado nesse `.txt` através do *PHP*.

Answer (score 0):

O que voce pode fazer é usar um Cron do Linux e seta-lo para rodar a cada x minutos ou segundos e ai voce fica verificando o arquivo. Voce pode fazer isso manualmente ou utilizar algum componente como esse:
https://github.com/peppeocchi/php-cron-scheduler

OU

Caso esse txt seja editado por algum outro programa, voce pode criar uma API com o PHP onde o programa que editou o txt envia uma mensagem dizendo que editou o file.